# python cyclic shifting of the characters in the string

Tags: python, subclass

Subclass sstr of the standard str type that implements the "<<" and ">>" methods as a cyclic shifting of the characters in the string.What trying to do is

```
 >>> s1 = sstr("abcde")
 >>> s1 << 0
'abcde'
 >>> s1 >> 0
'abcde'
 >>> s1 << 2
'cdeab'
>>> s1 >> 2
'deabc'
>>> s1 >> 5
 'abcde'

# my attempt:
import string
class sstr(str):
def __new__(self, other):
    return str.__new__(self, other.upper())
def __ilshift__(self, other):
    return str.__ilshift(other)
def __rshift__(self, other):
    return str.__rshift(other)
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is homework?

Comment: Homework and Daywork this lesson was lacking..........

Answer (score 2):

This smells like homework, so I'm not going to post actual code here. But to help, I will point out flaws I see in your code and an algorithm:

My python 2.7.2 reports no `__ilshift` or `__irshift` in `str`. Also, if you are trying to shift a string by a certain number of characters, then you shouldn't be shifting the variable you call `other`. You should be shifting `self` by `other` many characters. That being said, you're probably better off naming `other` as `n` or some such.

Now, I assume you know how circular shifting is supposed to work. The examples you provide get the message across well.

As a simple algorithm (easy to read/understand), try this (pseudo-code follows):

```
function __ilshift(self, n) { // self is the string to be shifted. n denotes how many characters to shift it by
    answer = copy()
    for i = 1 to n {
        answer = self[1:] //answer = everything in self excluding the first character
        answer += self[0] // append the first character of self to answer
    }
    return answer
}
```

The above solution would work. Though, it is quite inefficient. We know that when an n-character string is shifted by `n`, the result of the shifting is the string itself. When you think about this a little more, you realize that you end up shifting by `n % lengthOfSelf`. Thus, the `for i = 1 to n` turns into `for i = 1 to n%len(self)`.

Still, we can make this more efficient. To do this would require splicing `self` at the appropriate index, which I'll let you figure out, because I think this is homework.

Hope this gets you closer!

Comment: There is no need for a loop; you can just slice off the first `n` characters and put them at the end.

Comment: I know that, which is why I mentioned slicing towards the end of my post. However, since this appears to be homework, I didn't want to give away the best way to solve it right at the beginning; rather, I wanted to take the OP through the thought process. After all, if this really is homework, then it must be for CS101 or so, which means that the OP is not a very experienced programmer at this point and could therefore benefit from such a guided thought process

Comment: Thanks, for your help.I was able to complete the lesson once i used the correct methods __rshift__ and __lshift__.

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 << 0
```

This calls `__lshift__`, not `__ilshift__`. The `i` stands for in-place; you can't change a string in-place anyway, and aren't trying to here (you're trying to create a new value).

The problem with your actual code is that you're trying to implement the shift by just calling the base `str` class's shift. But the base `str` class *doesn't have* that shift operation - that's the entire reason you have this exercise!

Hint: put together two slices of the string. `'foobar' << 2` is `'obar' + 'fo'`. Can you see how to slice the string to get those? How do the numbers you use for the slices relate to the number specified for shifting?

Comment: I understand that I need to index and slice the string. If you look at my first post there is an example using the console, when I << or >> in the console I get:                                         TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'sstr' and 'int'        As you said in your post << and >> operator are not part of the string class.What do i need to do to be able to use them as arguments?

Comment: You need to define them in your subclass, you need to use the correct names as I suggested, and you need to write a definition that (a) **does not** try to call the base class definitions (because they don't exist); (b) use the indexing and slicing.