# Cycle through a string using a for loop

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm trying to use a single for loop to cycle over a string to print it out like this:

```
     s u p e r n a t u r a l
     u p e r n a t u r a l s
     p e r n a t u r a l s u
```

Here is my code so far:

```
   def main():
       first_Name = "s u p e r n a t u r a l"
       print(first_Name)
       for i in range(len(first_Name)):
           print(first_Name[i])


main()
```

Comment: If you need not loop over a long string with many times, how about just duplicate the string like 'HelloHelloHello' and use a single for loop to print it out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python cyclic shifting of the characters in the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826253/python-cyclic-shifting-of-the-characters-in-the-string)

Comment: You're actually making it more difficult by preinserting the extra spaces

Answer (score 1):

I have it in 4 lines:

```
li = list('supernatural')
for c in li:
    print ''.join(li)
    li.append(li.pop(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [11]:

S='s u p e r n a t u r a l'
SL=S.split(' ')
for i in range(len(S)-S.count(' ')):
    print ' '.join(SL[i:]+SL[:i])
s u p e r n a t u r a l
u p e r n a t u r a l s
p e r n a t u r a l s u
e r n a t u r a l s u p
r n a t u r a l s u p e
n a t u r a l s u p e r
a t u r a l s u p e r n
t u r a l s u p e r n a
u r a l s u p e r n a t
r a l s u p e r n a t u
a l s u p e r n a t u r
l s u p e r n a t u r a
```

Answer (score 0):

What a coincidence, I was doing the very same thing earlier in my consulting work! But seriously, to get you started on your homework, here are some ideas:

```
>>> print first_Name[0:] + ' ' + first_Name[:0]
s u p e r n a t u r a l
>>> print first_Name[1:] + ' ' + first_Name[:1]
 u p e r n a t u r a l s
>>> print first_Name[2:] + ' ' + first_Name[:2]
u p e r n a t u r a l s
```

Looks promising, at least the even numbers...

How to iterate through just even numbers?

```
>>> help(range)
```

`step` is your friend here.

```
>>> range(0, len(first_Name), 2)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22]
```

I bet you can (and should) figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def rshift(s, i):
    i = i % len(s)
    return s[-i:] + s[0:-i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = "12345"
    for i in range(len(s)):
        print rshift(s, -i)
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is made for a deque

```
import collections
d = collections.deque('supernatural')
for _ in range(len(d)):
    print(' '.join(d))
    d.rotate(-1)
```

Prints out:

```
s u p e r n a t u r a l
u p e r n a t u r a l s
p e r n a t u r a l s u
e r n a t u r a l s u p
r n a t u r a l s u p e
n a t u r a l s u p e r
a t u r a l s u p e r n
t u r a l s u p e r n a
u r a l s u p e r n a t
r a l s u p e r n a t u
a l s u p e r n a t u r
l s u p e r n a t u r a
```